# Calling & Searching through an Arraylist in a different class

Tags: java, class, collections, iterator

I am building a program to read a .txt file and extract the student data and store it in a collection. Then the user is supposed to be able to select several different queries. The query that I am asking for help with is to select all students graduating, for example, in 2014 and then print these results to the screen.

In short, how can I search throw the Arralist stored in ProcessRecords class for students who graduate in, for example, 2014? I just do not understand how to call it from a different class.

Below is my code:

First Class: With the main method

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class ProcessRecords {

 public static void AskUser() 
 throws Exception {
     Scanner preference = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Creating a new scanner will allow us to gather user input

     boolean flag=true; 
    //I will use this for my while loop
    while (flag) {
        System.out.println("What type of Search would you like to run?\n 1)Search for all students\n 2) Search for students graduating in a specific year\n 3)Search for students whose last name begins with a certain string\n");
        Query query = new Query(studentRecords);
        int searchType=preference.nextInt();
        //How would I throw an exception here if the user doesn't enter a number or enters a number less than 1 or great than 4
        //This variable will store what type of query the user would like to run

        switch(searchType) {
            case 1:
            System.out.println("Gathering Records for all students\n");
            //Call Query Method in the Query Class to return all students in the colletion
            case 2:
            System.out.println("What graduation year would you like to search for? \n");
            String yearsearch=preference.next();
            //Call Query Method to return students who are graduating in the specified year
            //Pass the "yearsearch" variable to the Query class
            case 3:
            System.out.println("What string would you like to search for? \n");
            String lstsearch=preference.next();
            //Call Query Method in the Query Class to return students who have the string in their last name
            //Also I need to pass the "lstsearch" variable to the Query class to search through last names                

        }
    }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 throws Exception
 {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("students.txt"));
    //This will import the file
    input.nextLine();
    //This will skip the headers in the file
    System.out.println("Processing file now...");
    //Let the user know that the file is being processed



    int id;
    String last;
    String first;
    int year;
    int i=1;
    // Declare variables that we will extract from the file

    //Now we will being processing the file with a while loop

    List<StudentRecord> studentRecords = new ArrayList<StudentRecord>();
    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        id=input.nextInt();
        last=input.next();
        first=input.next();
        year=input.nextInt();
        StudentRecord record = new StudentRecord(id, last, first, year);
        studentRecords.add(record);
        System.out.println(id + "  " + last + "  " + first + "  " + year + "\n");

    }
    System.out.println(" You have successfully read and printed from the file!");
    for (StudentRecord s : studentRecords)
        System.out.println(s.toString());
}
}
```

---

---

Second Class Student Records

```
    public class StudentRecord
 {
private int id;
private String last;
private String first;
private int year;

public StudentRecord(int id, String last, String first, int year)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.last=last;
    this.first=first;
    this.year=year;
}

public String toString()
{
    return id + "  " + last + "  " + first + "  " + year;
} 

public int getYear()
{

    return year;
}
}
```

---

---

Third Class (The one I am asking for help with)

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

  public class Query
 {
    //public static ProcessRecords studentrecord = new ProcessRecords();
     private List<StudentRecord> records;

     public Query(List<StudentRecord> records) {
         this.records = records;
    }

    public int getYear(int yearSearch) {
    int count = 0;

         for(StudentRecord record : records) {
             if(record.getYear() == yearSearch) {
                 count++;
             }
        }

       return count;
  }
  }
```

Added a new post!

Comment: you forgot to `break` your `case`s. If `searchType` is 1 than the code within all three cases will be executed.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any chance you could help me with gathering all the records in the ListArray for students graduating in a specific year?

Answer (score 0):

you have to make studentRecords a static variable or an instance variable,

put it like this, above the main :

```
public static List<StudentRecord> studentRecords ;
public static void main(String[] args)
throws Exception{

studentRecords = new ArrayList<StudentRecord>();
```

then just call it like this:

```
ProcessRecords.studentRecords
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code has multiple problems.**

1. Public variables are discouraged, getters/setters should be used to access object members. Eclipse `alt+s, r` will generate them for you
2. Names of your variables are misleading. What is the list you are accessing in Query?
3. Names of your classes are also (at minimum!) misleading. `ProcessRecords` as an action in particular seems bad. Shouldn't the class be a noun in this case, like `RecordsProcessor`? Shouldn't it give a hint to what it is actually doing? `StudentYearSearcher`?
4. You do not throw the list, you pass it (it's reference) as an argument, or access it somehow. You throw Exceptions

**Answer to your question**

There are multiple ways you can do it. One would be to use a singleton pattern and make the list statically accessible. Like this:

```
class StudentRecord {
  static List<StudentRecord> studentRecords;

  List<StudentRecord> getStudentRecords() {
    if (studentRecords == null) studentRecords= new ArrayList<StudentRecord>();
    return studentRecords;
  }

  //the reest of the class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be passing the entire list to the `getYear` method:

```
public static int getYear(List<StudentRecord> studentRecords, int yearsearch) {
      // ProcessRecords processRecords = new ProcessRecords();  <- don't need it
      int getYear= yearsearch;
      Iterator itr = studentRecords.iterator();

      // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your Query class look like this:

```
public class Query {

    private List<StudentRecord> records;

    public Query(List<StudentRecord> records) {
        this.records = records;
    }

    public int getYear(int yearSearch) {
       int count = 0;

       for(StudentRecord record : records) {
           if(record.getYear() == yearSearch) {
               count++;
           }
       }

       return count;
    }

    public int otherQuery() {
        // code for another query
    }
}
```

Then in your main class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class ProcessRecords {

    public static void AskUser(Query query) throws Exception {
        // all the code you have right now except the line where you
        // create a new Query object   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("students.txt"));
        //This will import the file
        input.nextLine();
        //This will skip the headers in the file
        System.out.println("Processing file now...");
        //Let the user know that the file is being processed

        int id;
        String last;
        String first;
        int year;
        int i=1;
        // Declare variables that we will extract from the file

        //Now we will being processing the file with a while loop

        List<StudentRecord> studentRecords = new ArrayList<StudentRecord>();

        while(input.hasNext()) {
            id=input.nextInt();
            last=input.next();
            first=input.next();
            year=input.nextInt();
            StudentRecord record = new StudentRecord(id, last, first, year);
            studentRecords.add(record);
            System.out.println(id + "  " + last + "  " + first + "  " + year + "\n");
        }

        System.out.println(" You have successfully read and printed from the file!");

        for (StudentRecord s : studentRecords) {
            System.out.println(s.toString());
        }

        Query query = new Query(studentRecords); // we've moved this out of AskUser method to here

        // now we call the AskUser method and pass it this query object we just
        // created so it can have access to it, meaning inside the AskUser method we can
        // say things like 'query.getYear(2014);'

        AskUser(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it say "Cannot find symbol -Variable StudentRecords when I compile the ProcessRecords class? I have updated my code in my last edit

Comment: The studentRecords variable doesn't exist in the AskUser() method. You need to create the Query object while you have access to the studentRecords list. You could do that right after you create the list (after the whole loop) in main. Or you could make studentRecords an instance variable and have access to it that way. Or you could make the Query object an instance variable and you'd have access to it in AskUser() that way too.

Comment: Looking at your code again the easiest way is probably to pass the Query object to the AskUser method. Make it in your main like I have above right after you've built the studentRecords variable (right above or below your success message). You'd have to change AskUser to "public static void AskUser(Query query)".

Comment: I am not understanding what you are saying? Is there any chance you could provide an example to show what you mean?

Comment: Edited my answer to give an example